# Command runs from command line, not from cron?

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I have the following command in my cron file:

```
*/15 * * * * NODE_ENV=production ~/bin/node ~/myapp/app.js > /var/log/nodelog/nodelog_`date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M"`.log
```

The command itself runs OK when copied and pasted into the bash shell, but the cron job keeps sending the following error message:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Why does it run OK from the command line, but fail in the cron job? Is there a difference between the syntax expected on the command line and that expected in cron?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From crontab manpage:

> Percent-signs  (%) in  the  command,  unless escaped with backslash
>   (\), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the
>   first % will be sent to the command as standard input.

Answer (score 1):

Crontabs are error prone for the following general reasons:

1. formatting requirements in crontab
2. permissions
3. environment

Hints

- Use **scripts**, not inline commands in your crontab (!) - avoids escaping issues
- Use absolute paths in your cron script.
- Test using `env -i ./myscript.sh`

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: ninja editing - was typing response _while reading queston_ :) You're right my first hunch wasn't the main problem here

Comment: Yes, I've seen you put in the escaping after I commented and unless you're a computer, probably started doing so before you read it :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the cron file permissions. If it is owned by you, then you can use ~. Otherwise use full path..!